# Canonnot Scan Code128 Barcode

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, code128

I'm trying to create a Crystal Report for printing Labels with Barcodes. I have tried this with a Code39 font already. Its scanable but as my string is long `1010001-BL/35` Its difficult to manage the Barcode on 10.95 cm width lable. Sometimes it doesn't get scanned.

As a solution I tried Code128 encoding (As its reducing the length of printed text). I used a 3rd party dll to encode the string (used the code 128 font with it). The output encode string for `1010001-BL/35` is `Í** È1-BL/35}Î`.

And the TextBox of Crystal Report correctly displaying the Barcode.

But I cannot read the barcode with any reader (Usually using a linear barcode reader).

Comment: Are you trying to scan a barcode on paper or on a computer monitor? If you are using a label printer, make sure the resolution is high enough.

Comment: @Verdolino On a paper using a ZDesigner Label printer. How to do that (resolution)?

Comment: What model # is the ZDesigner label printer?

Comment: The resolution is a spec of the printer itself, a number with units DPI.

Comment: You're using the same font as whatever dll says you need, right? And some scanners need to have Code128 reading enabled. Read your scanner's manual.

Comment: Printer is `Zebra TLP 2844` and the reader is `Symbol LS1203`.
I'm using the dll and the font from [jtbarton.com](http://www.jtbarton.com/Barcodes/BarcodeStringBuilderExample.aspx).